# How can I get meta of all datasource in a druid cluster?

Tags: metadata, druid

I want to get meta of all datasource in a druid cluster.

But I can't find the related queries format on Druid's official website.

I can only find the 'Segment Metadata' query which can query only one datasource's meta and 'Data Source Metadata' which can only get the  timestamp of latest ingested event for the dataSource.

Is there any way to get meta of all datasource in a druid cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the link   http://druid.io/docs/latest/design/coordinator.html and you can get many option as per your requirements.

Below will work for you :
Using postman make a GET call and you will get metadata of all datasources

```
/druid/coordinator/v1/metadata/datasources?full
```